# 18.04: Even with WaylandEnable=false gdm3 and lightdm only load sometimes

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, lightdm, gdm

I am happy to use either gdm3 or lightdm, but neither are stable on my Ubuntu 18.04 system, they will work for either one or several boots after I take corrective action, but inevitably this results in the greeter not loading - the last few times (at least) I noticed this was immediately after I did a *sudo apt update*. The graphics card on my Intel Core i5 system is an Nvidia GTX 970, and I manually installed nvidia-driver-415 using apt when I could not load a greeter as soon as I had installed.

Searching here and elsewhere, I have tried many things to resolve this, which I will outline below. If you know something else I can try - to get either greeter stable - please let me know.

**gdm3**

Even with *WaylandEnable=false* uncommented in */etc/gdm3/custom.conf*, I could never login, instead of the greeter I would see either a black screen or graphic distortion like a black screen with some pink lines across the top, and I am only able to login setting *nomodeset*.

[gdm3 sample distortion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxo1l.jpg)

With gd3 not working, I tried lightdm, and on encountering similar issues switched back to gdm3 again:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm3
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

This seemed to work - kind of, for the first few days I could boot most of the time. I have quiet splash permanently removed from my boot options, and boot was sometimes hanging on *Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon* as below:

[gdm3 fail 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Qv4.jpg)

Another time with gdm3 I saw the following output instead of the greeter:

[gdm3 fail 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFgsm.jpg)

[gdm3 fail 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7j78.jpg)

**lightdm**

When I use lightdm instead, and the greeter does not load, I see a flashing black screen with a single white underscore top left. I can never get to a TTY using ctrl + alt + f3/f4/f5, REISUB does not work, so I hard rebooted, the greeter loads with nomodeset, and from there without logging in I switch to a TTY and I have tried what I outline below. Sometimes if I just reboot again without nomodeset the greeter will just load properly, without my changing anything.

[lightdm underscore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vOml.jpg)

Observing these permissions:

```
-rw-------  1 dusf dusf      56 Jan  7 17:38 .Xauthority
-rw-------  1 dusf dusf   15886 Jan  7 17:38 .ICEauthority

drwxrwxrwt 16 root root 4096 Jan  7 17:45 /tmp
```

I input the following, and could login normally next reboot:

```
sudo chown dusf:dusf .Xauthority
sudo chown dusf:dusf .ICEauthority
sudo chmod a+wt /tmp
```

The next time the issue occurred I input the following, and could login next reboot:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

In *cat .xsession-errors*, I noticed the following line, which I thought *could* be relevant considering I see an underscore instead of a greeter?

```
_=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
```

Next temporary fix:

```
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak
```

Again:

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdmsudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

After a sudo apt upgrade a few days ago with the same issue recurring I input all of the following and everything seemed fine for a few days:

```
sudo apt upgradesudo apt purge lightdm
sudo apt purge gnome
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-415
reboot
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
sudo apt install nvidia-415
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-415
reboot
sudo apt purge xorg-* xserver-xorg
sudo apt install xorg xserver-xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xorg
sudo apt purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt purge gnome-desktop-environment
apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt purge lightdm
sudo apt install --reinstall lightdm
```

The next time the issue occurred I noticed in my .bash_history the last commands I input were:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and I uploaded the following logs:

[/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wkfmNrrctG/)

[cat /var/log/kern.log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/g9bRKpMnxW/)

[cat .xsession-errors](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KhjrKYwmdj/)

I read adding an *xrandr* line to some files may be the next step, but the actual lines seem to be system specific, and their are recommendations on adding them to different files.

How can I begin to resolve the issue, either with gdm3 or lightdm please?